# How to use MediaManager plugin and play and pause icon in Xamarin.Forms project

Tags: xamarin.forms

Update:

It's playing well, but when finished playing it's not showing the play button. I have tried I couldn't get it well. Maybe I spiked something else were.

How can I show the play button when a player finished playing?

HomePage.xaml

```
                     <Button ImageSource="{Binding PlayIcon}"
                            Command="{Binding PlayCommand}"
                            HorizontalOptions="End"
                            VerticalOptions="End"/>
```

HomePage.xaml.cs

```
        public HomePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            isPlaying = true;
        }

        private bool isPlaying;
        public bool IsPlaying
        {
            get { return isPlaying; }
            set
            {
                isPlaying = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PlayIcon));
            }
        }

        public string PlayIcon { get => isPlaying ? "play.png" : "pause.png"; }

        public ICommand PlayCommand => new Command(Play);

        private async void Play()
        {
            if (isPlaying)
            {
                await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play("file:///android_asset/running.mp3");
                IsPlaying = true; ;
            }
            else
            {
                await CrossMediaManager.Current.Pause();
                IsPlaying = false; ;
            }
        }
```

Thank you for your contribution.

Comment: What is your question?  You've told us what you want to do and shown us your code, but haven't asked a question.  Is there some problem with the code you have?

Comment: How to play an audio from Local Folder using MediaManager Plugin in Xamarin.forms project and to change the ImageButton from play icon to pause icon and push it to normal play icon

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include those questions.  The [docs](https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager#other-play-possibilities) cover all the different overloads available for the Play method.  Have you read them?

Comment: and is there a reason you can't use the same method to toggle the icons that was suggested in response to your last question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to play an asset, use this syntax

```
private async void PlayButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // update the button's image
        ((Button)sender).ImageSource = ImageSource.FromFile("pause.png");

        wait CrossMediaManager.Current.Play("file:///android_asset/long-test.mp3");

    }
```

ref: https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager/issues/840

the [docs](https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager#hook-into-events) contains a list of events supported by the control, including a `MediaItemFinished` event

Comment: Thanks. Secondly I want to know how to change the play icon to pause icon and push it to normal play icon

Comment: either change the visibility, as was suggested in your previous question, or just update the buttons ImageSource

Comment: Yes, I want you to show me the way

Comment: you want me to show you how to do the exact thing that was explained to you in your last question?

Comment: Look at the above question, I made some amendment. Thank you for your concern.

Comment: please read the docs: https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager#hook-into-events

Comment: Sir, Look again at the above question, I made some amendment. Thank you.

Comment: You don’t appear to be doing anything with the MediaItemFinished event

Comment: I'm new for that, please help me

Comment: It's ok now I solved it. Thank you Jason.